# Windows 2003 Domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

I have a win 2K3 domain controller that has sudddenly started logging about  60 events a second. All events are ID 538, 540 and 576

All events pertain to Security Audit of the machine itself logging in successfully. a typical entry is

**Event Id 540
Successful Network Logon:
  User Name: <machinename>$**

Any pointers to how I can diagnose this? CPU and memory are normal on the machine.

Comment: This is normal behavior from what I have seen.  But 60 of those a second seems like a lot, but you did not tell us how many machines you have on your network.

Comment: While there  are about 80 machines connect to the DC, all events pertain to the DC machine itself logging on.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

It is more than likely being caused by an audit privilege setting.  Check those and you my find your answer.